# Vectors that span normal bundle of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

If $E_{1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-kx\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ and $E_{2}=cos\psi\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + sin \psi\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ span tangent space of $M$, where $M$ is a two-dimensional submanifold of $R^{4}$, where $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\}$ is a basis of $R^{4}$. How can we find vectors that span normal bundle to $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve for vectors that are orthogonal to $E_1$ and $E_2$ at a point, $P$,  on $M$ -- you will find a two-dimensional basis -- call that vector space spanned by that basis $N_P$. Then, $\cup_{P\in M} N_P$ is the normal bundle.